Topologically dense transversals for equivalence relations
This is primarily a query about terminology.
(Standard Set Theory) Definition 1: A transversal for an equivalence relation $\sim$ on a
set $X$ is a subset of $X$ that contains exactly one point in each
equivalence class. Equivalently, it is the image of a section
of the quotient map $X\to X/{\sim}$.
Let $X$ be a topological space.
Definition 2: Let's say that an equivalence relation on $X$ is weakly transversally dense if there exists a dense transversal.
Definition 3: Let's say that an equivalence relation on $X$ is strongly transversally dense if every transversal is dense.
I expect that Definitions 2 and 3 appear in various guises in the literature, presumably with names other that the ones that I've made up. I'd like to know whether there are standard names for these notions, and also for results/references/discussions about "transversally dense sets" that appear in the literature. (I've included AG as a tag since the particular case that I'm interested in is that of an algebraic variety $X$ with its Zariski topology.)

Do you know an easy example of a non-trivial (e.g., not ${\sim} = {=}$, but maybe more than that) strongly transversally dense relation?

@LSpice (1) Take $X=S^1\subset\mathbb C^*$, and define $a\sim b$ if there are non-zero integers $m$ and $n$ so that $a^m=b^n$. Then I think that this is a strongly transversally dense equivalence relation on $S^1$ for the usual topology on the circle.  (2) Take $X=\mathbb Q$ with the Zariski topology (closed sets are the finite sets) and $a\sim b$ if $a-b$ is an even integer.

@JoeSilverman Would you explain why the first space $X=\mathcal{S}^1$ is strongly transversal?  Isn't each equivalence class dense, so I can use the axiom of choice to pick a single element from each class in any interval (or the upper half plane)?  For $\alpha$ irrational, $e^{2\pi i m\alpha}$,$m\in \mathbb{N}$ is dense, so choose $m_{\alpha}$ such that $Im(e^{2\pi i m_{\alpha}\alpha})>0$.  Also, $e^{2\pi i\frac{p}{q}}$ are equivalent for $\frac{p}{q}$ rational and non-zero, since given any $p,q,s,t\in \mathbb{N}$, $(e^{2\pi i \frac{p}{q}})^{sq}=(e^{2\pi i\frac{s}{t}})^{pt}=e^{2\pi i ps}=1.$

@user65023 Ah, yes, that seems right. I was just trying to quickly think of an example that worked with the usual real or complex topology. As I mentioned, I'm actually interested in the algebraic geometry/Zariski topology setting. The second example should be okay.

Thanks @JoeSilverman.  Interesting question, but I'll need to understand the Zariski top to have anything useful to say.
